# I want to delete a particular cookie using Capybara within Cucumber test and don't want to use Webkit / Poltergeist

Tags: capybara

I have tried a couple of ways like using `browser.manage.delete_cookie` and also setting cookie to empty by doing something like this : `page.driver.browser.manage.set_cookie("#{'cookie_name'}:")` but none of them helped.

This is my Step Defn file

```
Given('I am on Learn Page') do
  page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1800,990)
  #tried this to click on the radio button from chrome settings to disable all cookies, but failed
  visit "chrome://settings/cookies" 
  find('.//*[@id="label"]/text()').click
  #find('#radioCollapse').click
  
  
  #failed with this too
  visit "https://mylearnwebsite.com/"
  browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
  browser.manage.delete_cookie 'my_cookie'
     
   #and with this as well
   page.driver.browser.manage.set_cookie("{'my_cookie'}:")
end
```

All of them either says, unable to locate element or `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError`

I am a newbie to Capybara and trying to automate a couple of web application features using the same.It would be a great help if anyone from the group suggest how to proceed here.

Comment: What driver are you using? Also it would be a help to people if you show your test and any errors you’re getting

Comment: @ThomasWalpole : I have updated my details above. Please help check. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be on a page where the cookie would be valid in order to interact with the cookies (WebDriver spec limitation).  Assuming that `https://mylearnwebsite.com/` is the site where the cookie is valid and you're using the selenium driver then

```
visit "https://mylearnwebsite.com/"
page.driver.browser.manage.delete_cookie 'my_cookie' # this is driver specific
page.refresh # to reload the page without the cookie
...
```

would delete the cookie. Since you haven't shown what you're actually checking after removing the cookie it's hard to guess what behavior you're looking to actually test, so the code above is just calling `refresh` to see the page state without the cookie.

Noe: From a general system/feature testing purpose it's usually not valuable to manually interact with cookies, you're generally better off just testing the user behaviors which have a side-effect of modifying cookies.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. 

Actually, there is a bootstrap modal which is getting generated from a 3rd party vendor which is failing my test. I just want to block this from the script so that my test can continue and pass. And this modal is appearing in random pages, so i just need to block it during my initial load, so that it won't appear again throughout my test.

Can you please suggest if there is some other way to handle this?

Comment: @Dannie You can’t block a cookie on initial load using  just capybaraa mad selenium since you need to already be on the page to interact with the cookie for that page. To do what you want it sounds like you need to use a programmable proxy like puffing_billy which will let you block external scripts, cookies, etc

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas. For now, I am using the following snippet to handle the popups [which is again not what I am looking for] which is helping me to get rid of those modals.

```page.within_frame('wiz-iframe-intent') do
   find("span.ct_interstitialclose").click
end```

I'll try your suggestion and will let you know if that helps.